# How to set minimum thickness to plot component in ant-design donut chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, components, antd, donut-chart

I have 3 components in my donut chart.

But one of the component's value is very less. (0.3%)

This component is barely visible in my donut chart

How to set up a minimum thickness for a component in the ant design donut chart?

Docs: https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/pie/donut#basic

[image]

Comment: You can update the value in the dataset to increase the width.

Comment: That won't be ideal! If I have 3 to 4 such values I should increase all of those. And changing values affects everything in the chart ( value shown in tooltip, .... )